# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with GIGABYTE Geforce GTX 750

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics

I noticed there was a lot of posts regarding other Geforce GTX 750 cards however I am not sure if those are compatible with GIGABYTE's card or if they are actually the same product. So apologies in advance if this will be a repeat question.

So I have bought a new Gigabyte Geforce GTX 750 (Model Name: GV-N750OC-2GI) graphics card. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with the latest updates applied.
Before I install the card, is this compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 and I should just install the card and away I go, or is there anything special I may need to do?

Will I need to upgrade to 16.04.1?

Thanks in advance!

Update #1:
Attempted to use the default drivers (Open drivers version) and it crashes. I am attempting to use the NVidia drivers now.

Comment: I cannot see it [here](http://free3d.org/). But open-source drivers might work. Just give it a try!

Comment: You probably will need nomodeset to boot after installed. Once you install nVidia proprietary driver from repository then it should work. You may be able to install nVidia driver first, but have to use synaptic as driver updates will not see a card to install. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Or use recovery mode and boot to command line to manually install nVidia driver.

Comment: @oldfred If it doesn't work right away and I install the older video card, I should still be able to use the older video card correct?

Comment: What was older video card? If not same version driver, you must totally purge/uninstall old driver before installing new driver. A new driver does not auto uninstall old driver and then you get conflicts.